# Using LOCK TABLES to handle multiple table requests

Tags: mysql

The following script logic is designed allow multiple users to make a tee time reservation while competing for the same time slot.

The object of the script is to allow a user to check to see if a tee time is available and reserve it without any other user doing the same. Many users will attempt to make reservations simultaneously and some may want to reserve the same reservation time.

1. Several users simultaneously try to access a table to reserve a time
2. The first user succeeds and the script locks the table with table write:

   - LOCK TABLE teetimes WRITE;

     - All other requests must wait until the first user unlocks the table
3. The locking script then:

   - checks the table for the requested time availability
   - if available, it saves the time in a 'reserved' column in the locked table and then
   - Unlocks the table with UNLOCK TABLES
   - any subsequent requests for the 'reserved' time will not be allowed
4. The next user in line now gains access to the newly unlocked table & repeats the above
5. The original locking user then continues to select and then save relative additional info into the now un-locked table.
6. The script saves the requested time info and exits.

Questions:

Does this logic make sense?
Will the table unlock automatically if the locking script unexpectedly ends before UNLOCK TABLES executes? A MySQL error could occur or the user connection may end abruptly.

During the execution of the script, I can print out verification that the table is locked after locking and can print out verification that the table is unlocked after calling UNLOCK TABLES using: "show open tables like 'teetimes';". It seems to work correctly.

I would like to see what happens when a script tries to access a locked table so I intentionally allowed the script to execute without calling UNLOCK TABLES and left the SESSION window open in the browser. I printed out verification that the table was still locked using:
$sql = "show open tables like 'teetimes';"; at the end of the script, and the query showed the table  still locked.

Then I checked the database using phpMyAdmin expecting to see the table still locked... but it was not.

I would like to test whether or not locking the table will actually prevent other queries from accessing it during the locked period and I'd like to know how it got unlocked when I did not query UNLOCK TABLES and left the SESSION window open.

Any comments and help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had any replies yet but found out these things through experimenting:

1. as soon as the script ends, the table unlocks whether or not you submitted UNLOCK TABLES. So even in my script where I did not call unlock tables, The table was unlocked as soon as the script finished. That's why I did not see that the table was locked when checking it.

I added a timer in my script for 60 seconds, that gave me time to check the database and see the table was indeed locked.

I would still like to know for sure that the table will unlock automatically if the script experienced an error or connection disruption.